# Are there other algorithms like LSM tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, nosql

There are many strategies for disk space (and memory) management in databases. 
I try to track the best ones like log-structured merge tree in form of BigTable (and HBase, Hypertable, Cassandra) or fractal tree used in TokuDB. From what I have mentioned it is easy to guess, I mean algorithms what use wisely resources (for example avoiding I/O and scale well).

Are there other algorithms like LSM tree? Just direct me.

Comment: Note that Bigtable doesn't use Log-structured storage.

Answer (score 0):

currently , google release levelDB （you can search it in google）;
People say it is the memtable sstable implemetion of  google's bigtable!
I think it is a simple version after read some source code!

Hope it can give some help

Answer (score 0):

and nessDB.
It's using a simple LSM-Tree, https://github.com/shuttler/nessDB

Answer (score 0):

H2Database's MVStore uses [Log Structured Storage](https://www.h2database.com/html/mvstore.html#logStructured), a slight similar to LSM-Tree

[Fragmented LSM-Tree](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~vijay/papers/sosp17-pebblesdb.pdf), implemented in [PebblesDB](https://github.com/utsaslab/pebblesdb)

[WiscKey](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/fast16/fast16-papers-lu.pdf), implemented in this [contest project](https://github.com/neoremind/2018-polar-race)